# Replace part of a matched string in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have the following matched strings:

```
punctacros="Tasla"_TONTA  
punctacros="Tasla"_SONTA  
punctacros="Tasla"_JONTA  
punctacros="Tasla"_BONTA
```

I want to replace only a part (before the underscore) of the matched strings, and the rest of it should remain the same in each original string.

The result should look like this:

```
TROGA_TONTA  
TROGA_SONTA  
TROGA_JONTA  
TROGA_BONTA
```

Comment: What is a matched string? And why do you have quotes in the middle of them?

Comment: matched means that my regex picked them from a body of text. Quotes are just literal characters in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

This should work:

```
from re import sub
with open("/path/to/file") as myfile:
    lines = []
    for line in myfile:
        line = sub('punctacros="Tasla"(_.*)', r'TROGA\1', line)
        lines.append(line)
with open("/path/to/file", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.writelines(lines)
```

Result:

```
TROGA_TONTA  
TROGA_SONTA  
TROGA_JONTA  
TROGA_BONTA
```

---

Note however, if your file is exactly like the sample given, you can replace the `re.sub` line with this:

```
line = "TROGA_"+line.split("_", 1)[1]
```

eliminating the need of Regex altogether.  I didn't do this though because you seem to want a Regex solution.

Comment: The thing is that i have to first find these kinds of strings in the text and then have to replace them with a new string, keeping parts (after underscore) of them unchanged. Therefore, it has to be done by a regex engine which first finds them and then replace them.

Comment: I have to first find them in a text file and then replace them. I am not going to extract them out of the tex. They will remain in the text file after replacing their parts.

Comment: @Coddy - Oh, you should have mentioned that in your question.  See my edit.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.replace('punctacross="Tasla"', 'TROGA_')
```

where mystring is string with those four lines. It will return string with replaced values.

Comment: I have to first find them in a text file and then replace it. I am not going to extract them out of the tex. They will remain in the text file after replacing their parts.

Comment: Yes, you will. Strings are immutable, replace() method will return new string with replaced parts, without modifying your file or original string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace everything before the first underscore, try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

data = ['punctacros="Tasla"_TONTA',
'punctacros="Tasla"_SONTA',  
'punctacros="Tasla"_JONTA',  
'punctacros="Tasla"_BONTA',
'somethingelse!="Tucku"_CONTA']

for s in data:
    print('TROGA' + s[s.find('_'):])
```